# Shiro Filter without redirect

Tags: java, ajax, shiro

I have a REST-Interface that gets called from the Front-End code via jquery-Ajax-Requests. The called url is secured with the following shiro.ini:

```
/api/** = authc
```

If the user is not authenticated Shiro wants to redirect to the login-Url and the ajax-Request can't handle that. I'd prefer a HTML status code as answer.
What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement a custom shiro filter. 
Something like this:

```
        import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

        import java.io.IOException ;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse ;

        import org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authz.AuthorizationFilter ;
        import org.apache.shiro.web.util.WebUtils ;

        public class LocalhostFilter extends AuthorizationFilter {

            private static final String message = "Access denied.";

            @Override
            protected boolean isAccessAllowed(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, Object mappedValue) throws Exception {
                //do something when access allowed
                return true;       
 }

            @Override
            protected boolean onAccessDenied(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException {
                HttpServletResponse httpResponse ;
                try { httpResponse = WebUtils.toHttp(response); }
                catch (ClassCastException ex) { 
                    // Not a HTTP Servlet operation
                    return super.onAccessDenied(request, response) ;
                }
                if ( message == null )
                    httpResponse.sendError(403) ;
                else
                    httpResponse.sendError(403, message) ;
                return false ;  // No further processing.
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it working by extending the FormAuthenticationFilter. You put me on the right track.

Comment: How can I configure my application context telling him to use this custom shiro filter?

Answer (score 0):

Responding to question:

> How can I configure my application context telling him to use this custom shiro filter?

The application context will pick up changes from *shiro.ini* file. Define the custom filter in its [main] section and use it in the [urls] section on applicable URL patterns.

```
[main]
myLocalhostFilter = my.package.LocalhostFilter

...

[urls]
...
/api/** = myLocalhostFilter
```